# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name - please tell mi where is the error

Tags: spring, controller, thymeleaf

What am I doing wrong?
The following error appears after entering http://localhost:8080/new

2020-05-22 11:44:19.786 ERROR 1632 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template "new_employee_form": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "new_employee_form" - line 81, col 73)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "new_employee_form" - line 81, col 73)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'address' available as request attribute

This is my Controller with two methods. 
The problem occurs after performing the GET method and going to the template to input field.

```
  @GetMapping("/new")
    public String showCreateFormForEmployeeAndAddresses(Model model) {

        if(addressService.getCheck()== false) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                addressService.newAddress(new Address());
            }
        }
        List<Address> newAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        newAddresses.addAll(addressService.getAddresses());

        System.out.println(newAddresses);
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee()).addAttribute("addresses", newAddresses);
        return "new_employee_form";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEmployeeAndAddress(@ModelAttribute @Valid Employee employee,
                                        BindingResult bindingResultEmployee,
                                        @ModelAttribute @Valid ArrayList<Address> addressesFromForm ,
                                        BindingResult bindingResultAddress, Model model)  {

        System.out.println("Są błędy");
        if(bindingResultEmployee.hasErrors() || bindingResultAddress.hasErrors()) {

            bindingResultEmployee.getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
                System.out.println(error.getObjectName() + " " + error.getDefaultMessage());
                }
            );
            bindingResultAddress.getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
                        System.out.println(error.getObjectName() + " " + error.getDefaultMessage());
                    }
            );
            model.addAttribute("employee", employee).addAttribute("form", addressesFromForm);
            return "new_employee_form";

        } else{
              System.out.println("Brak błędów");
//            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
//            Runnable runnableEmployee = () -> employeeService.saveEmployeeToDB(employee);
//            AddressRepository addressesList = addressesFromForm.getAddresses();
//            Runnable runnableAddress = () -> addressService.saveAddressToDB(addressesList);
//
//            executor.submit(runnableEmployee);
//            executor.submit(runnableAddress);

            return "redirect:/employees";
        }
    }
```

This is part of thymeleaf view:

```
            <div th:object="${addresses}">
                <div th:each="address : ${addresses}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${address.street}"/>
                        <div class="text-danger"><p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address.street')}" th:errors="${address.street}"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thymeleaf cannot handle an array of objects. You need to create a new AddressesCreation Dto object that will contain a list of addresses and directly refer to it from the controller.